# having problem with closing a form that has input

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to close all forms but this code doesnt work. Could someone give me the right code?

```
private Form0 _form0 = null;
public Form1(Form0 form0)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   form0.Hide();
   _form0 = form0;
}
```

`form0` show a demo when user press the entrance button form1 will be shown.

```
private void ToolStripMenuItem7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1 form1 = new Form1(form0);
   form1.Dispose();
   form1.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: What are you doing exactly in your method `ToolStripMenuItem7_Click` and what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ToolStripMenuItem7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(Form1 form1 = new Form1(form0))
    {
       form1.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean form1.close(); ,dont u? no diffrence. it doesnt work!

Comment: @shiny - I was guessing that since you have `Form1` in a ToolStripMenuItem click event, that its a separate `Form` that you want to show.  You dont show anywhere in the posted code where `Form1` or `Form0` is shown (ie. where is from1.Show() or form1.ShowDialog() and where is form0.Show() or form0.ShowDialog())?

Comment: at first form0 is shown then in form0.cs I have:    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1(this);
            form1.Show();
        }

Comment: @shiny - Is `ToolStripMenuItem7_Click` in form0.cs or form1.cs?

Comment: I had a menuBar that exit(=ToolStripMenuItem7) is one of its option.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Exit();` will close all forms and entire application as well.

Comment: I useed it but nothing happened

Comment: also there was an error:Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.